# Authorization Middleware laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, permissions, middleware

i have this route

```
 Route::resource('companies','CompaniesController')->only( 'edit','create')->middleware('can:companies');
```

and assign it to authorization companies 
which admin have this permission as you see :

```
 user->roles->permissions->companies
```

and i can't still enter companies create page

Answer (score 1):

your middleware should map to a method in your Policy. so assuming for example you already have a CompanyPolicy with a create method, your middleware should look like this:

```
->middleware('can:create,companies');
```

Comment: but if i don't work with Policy ? can i know the permission directly ?>

Comment: using the `can` middleware requires you to create content policies. I would recommend having a read of content Policies documentation 
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `Gate` in you `AuthServiceProvider` like

```
Gate::define('compagnie', function(User $user) {
    // write the condition which determine if the user is allow to perfrorm this action
    return $user->roles->permissions->companies;
});
```

Comment: you are welcome! happy to know that you have solve your issue